# How to fix the Error which getting users.profile.get in SLACK

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am trying to get the User account information for which I am trying to Test using Slack Tester.

```
api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.get/test
```

when I give my Token and click on Test I am getting the error below:

```
{
    "OK": false,
    "error": "missing_scope",
    "needed": "users.profile:read",
    "provided": "identify,bot,incoming-webhook"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your token is missing the required scopes.

As the error message says you need the scope `users.profile:read` to run the API method `users.profile.get`.

To get a token with the needed scope you need to add the scope to your Slack app and reinstall into the workspace.

Also this API method will not work with bot tokens. You need to provide a user token aka Oauth Access Token.

Comment: I given the Token of oAuth Access itself.

Comment: Apparently it does not have the needed scope. Did you add the sope and then reinstalled your Slack app to the workplace?

Comment: No. I didnt and i am not sure how to do that. I seen few post but not able to do that. BTW this i am trying in my personal Slack and i am the Admin

Comment: OK, that is most likely why its not working. Do you have a Slack app? Open your app management page from the [dashboard](https://api.slack.com/apps), go to Oauth & Permissions page. Add the scope. Click on "Reinstall App"

Comment: Great that it work. To mark this answer as solution click the checkmark next to the arrows. Upvotes are also always appreciated.